# Stored procedure using if statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, xampp

I have here stored procedure:

```
delimiter //
create procedure insert(p int, n varchar(10), d date, q int)
begin
select pname if(pname!=n) 
  then 
    insert into prod(p,n,d,q)values(p,n,d,q)
  else quant=quant + q;
from prod;
end;
//
```

This stored procedure will add records to the table `prod` if `pname` and `n` are not equal ELSE if they are equal, the quant will be updated and added by the value of q. This idea is not working can you help me? How to achieve this one?

Comment: is there another answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
....
BEGIN 
    DECLARE p CHAR DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT pname FROM prod WHERE pname = n LIMIT 1 INTO p FOR UPDATE;
    IF(p) THEN
        UPDATE prod SET quant = quant + q WHERE pname = n;
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO prod(p,n,d,q) values(p,n,d,q);
    END IF;
END;
```

There are simpler ways to do it if you have a UNIQUE key on pname in prod.

Comment: Why did you declare the p? It's already declared in the procedure arguments right? And what do you mean the LIMIT 1 part?